# "The directory name is not valid" error in opening the word process by c#

Tags: c#, ms-word

I want to create a docx file and open that to changed it by user ,after closing the file I want to convert the word file to `byte[]` and save it to database .

The word process can't open the path and give me an Error: **the directory name is not valid**

```
string fileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + @"\tempTenderCondition.docx";
var doc = DocX.Create(fileName);
doc.Save();

Process p = Process.Start("WINWORD.EXE", fileName);
p.WaitForExit();
//----------------------
FileStream stream = new FileStream(
   fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(stream);

_publicCondition= reader.ReadBytes((int)stream.Length);

reader.Close();
stream.Close();

return _publicCondition;
```

Comment: What is the result of the filename variable?

Comment: E:\\samta application3\\samtaApplication\\bin\\Debug\\tempTenderCondition.docx

Comment: It may be the space in the first folder name

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the space in the folder path

E:\samta application3\samtaApplication\bin\Debug\tempTenderCondition.docx

or force quotes around the string with \"